# Is something wrong with my Puppy Linux installation?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, puppy-linux

I've just installed `bionicpup64-8.0-uefi.iso` on VirtualBox.

[image]

**Now there's something that's bothering me: the installation option is still there.**
Please explain. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `install` application allows you to install Puppy Linux onto a hard drive, USB key, or SD card etc.  It also allows you to install other application via the Puppy Package Manager.

It's unclear why you expect this `install` application to be removed once the system has been install on a disk.  It could still be useful for installing Puppy Linux on additional media, or for installing further applications.

There is nothing wrong with your installation of Puppy Linux.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.